# How to use AJAX to search Google Images?

Tags: ajax, json, google-api, google-image-search

I'm trying to pull pictures from Google Images using AJAX and a color filter.

The [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/) has been deprecated, and use of the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) is encouraged instead. However, in reading the Programmer's Guides found there, I see no option for *global* search instead of *site-specific* search. It says [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/getting_started#set_up_cse) to set up a custom search engine, but this requires the searching to be limited to a specific URL!

There is a [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8448788/805556) which links to a [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/iNbeR8IEjhc%5B1-25%5D). The only solutions offered there are either to use the deprecated API, something I'm rather loath to do since access has been limited, or to use the Bing API instead, which cannot filter searches by colors.

Are there really no other solutions? Is it impossible to perform a global Google Images search using AJAX?

Comment: Maybe they don't want you to show their results without the advertisements :D

Comment: That would really go against their policy (or show) of openness!