# How to get city sights images from Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api, google-photos

I use Google Places Photos Api and I want to get sights images for selected city by placeid or city title.

I try 2 methods:

**1.** f.e. I send request (used London placeid)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI&key=API_KEY
```

get location from response

```
"lat": 51.5073509
"lng": -0.1277583
```

next step is request to

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.5073509,-0.1277583&radius=5000&types=park|church|cafe|food|bar|night_club|stadium|store&keyword=&key=API_KEY
```

response contain many objects with placeid, that i use for new request like first

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ1eu1vwgIdkgRwjsifpZERQc&key=API_KEY
```

response contain photo_reference object which is the part of my image source

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=CoQBcwAAAMLCk4X_WMliqIfISe-mgxRadycuzApodVcaCrTMGP6wQXJaquATedXMkvnjuLAfTG9xzBYQfSNm3iXV07wxHr_X_WDhfjz_yQjmqCYlKwYwK5hH-nl9qi-4ZZqKKtFuphFEY8ka25GYN2sTNMdd0v99j7YCzpR-lHJnl0zA9QoPEhBA5CnCgElBAU7Z92VTShg2GhQUes4fTRKiJlW6rYKYEaNilauWaA&key=API_KEY&maxwidth=1200
```

[result image](http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2015/04/1cb8e57ddc78bafa43c6162f7f7ce3e8.jpg)

It's not the best photo of London...

**2.** 
Using textsearch with param query=sights+in+London

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=sights+in+London&key=API_KEY
```

This request return response which are contains photo_reference objects.
finally request is

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=CnRnAAAAlLsg47UJRPVLdM8_sUbeLSia70EJ_mTisVDfCDTVUYNXl-35BGqzRARtq-Lt1CNcBWy3sKigfBVuF0iCr9-xqp1khK2l5JV3806LKvZrHJCaONYW35UBxxIIwxvxV-df4I4hg6f_zgeeIkWXGSYQhhIQNGYJl0fvHb3HslymbhH1thoUdLhGe8rJVCnyl_y0xAagzkFWs-Y&key=API_KEY&maxwidth=1200
```

[result image](http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2015/04/e942193024313404fe6803f035d5f310.jpg)

How can i get images like [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=sights%20in%20london&biw=1919&bih=919&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=T20vVeqOHsmbsgGpjYHgCA&sqi=2&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg)

Comment: Flicker and panoramio api are great to get photos of any place.

Answer (score 1):

The Places API directly returns some photos for cities like London now.  For example your query for London by Place ID:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI&key=API_KEY
```

Includes [this photo of the Place of Westminster](https://www.google.com/maps/place/London,+UK/@51.528308,-0.3817765,300343a,13.1y,90t/data=!3m7!1e2!3m5!1s-ef7S6Y3nedg%2FVzhksHXF_dI%2FAAAAAAAAK0U%2FC-PUiikt2IIPLYJPEc8dgfizVHvOgAg5ACLIB!2e4!3e12!7i3264!8i1836!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99!8m2!3d51.5073509!4d-0.1277583!6m1!1e1) that is also shown on Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'd be looking for an API that surfaces Google Image Search results, and there is one: Google Custom Search
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview

I'm not familiar with it, but there's already an answer for how to get just images out of your requests to this API:
[Google custom search for images only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448788/google-custom-search-for-images-only)