# Pass an image get a list of URLs matching the image, HOW?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search, google-image-search

I'm essentially trying to do a reverse image search, i.e. I want to pass in an image and get back a results list of instances on the web where that image is found.  I know Google's old API that did this is depreciated, I see some answers on SO (e.g. [Google custom search for images only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448788/google-custom-search-for-images-only))  that talk about doing an image search with Google's Custom Search API, but every time I dig into the code they are retrieving images from a string rather than what I'm trying to do.  Is there currently any API that will help me with what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry. I cannot write comments yet. How about this? https://github.com/tanaikech/goris
Recently, I found this. I don't know whether this is what you want.