# Is it possible to search Youtube thumbnails?

Tags: youtube-api

Suppose I have an image of a video thumbnail, and I want to retrieve all videos with a similar thumbnail. Does Youtube or Google's API provide a method to achieve this?

Comment: have you search [google api search image example](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+api+search+image+example) - I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696898/12511801) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10141902/12511801).